# PHP get array value from randomly nested, randomly outputted XML and then get associated values related to first value search

Tags: php, xml, nested

Ugh. PHP dummy here sorry. Searched and searched here, but search foo not good enough. I feel like I'm dancing around an answer, but array_filter, array_search, recursive etc. I'm just not getting a handle on it mentally haha.

I have this sample from an XML export where the ordering of the XML is NOT consistent nor well formed and the nesting levels are even different at times etc. etc. so I can't grab values based on where it is specifically in the export, which even dummy me could do:

```
<INFRA>
<GUID>7C32C0A2-EF31-11E9-8128-4CCC6A98779E</GUID>
<ID>501</ID>
<NAME>P Cedar</NAME>
<TYP>36</TYP>
<TYPKRZ>50_IN_36_PARKPLATZ</TYPKRZ>
<TYPNAME>parking place</TYPNAME>
<STATUS>open</STATUS>
<STATUSWERT k="SONSTIGE" v="miscellaneous">1</STATUSWERT>
</INFRA>
```

In this instance I need to find/search for unique string `<NAME>P Cedar</NAME>` no matter where in the export it may end up. Then I need to assign a variable to the `<STATUS>` of that particular `<INFRA><NAME>` so I can do some operators against it. TIA!

Comment: Are you using an XML parser library? It should have methods for searching for a `<NAME>` tag, then find the enclosing `<INFRA>` tag, and finally find the `<STATUS>` within that so you can update it.

Comment: you can use the SimpleXML extension, which provides an easy way to handle XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```php
$xml = <<<XML
<ROOT>
    <NESTED>
        <INFRA>
            <GUID>7C32C0A2-EF31-11E9-8128-4CCC6A98779E</GUID>
            <ID>501</ID>
            <NAME>P Cedar</NAME>
            <TYP>36</TYP>
            <TYPKRZ>50_IN_36_PARKPLATZ</TYPKRZ>
            <TYPNAME>parking place</TYPNAME>
            <STATUS>open</STATUS>
            <STATUSWERT k="SONSTIGE" v="miscellaneous">1</STATUSWERT>
        </INFRA>
        <INFRA>
            <GUID>7C32C0A2-EF31-11E9-8128-4CCC6A98779E</GUID>
            <ID>501</ID>
            <NAME>D John</NAME>
            <TYP>36</TYP>
            <TYPKRZ>50_IN_36_PARKPLATZ</TYPKRZ>
            <TYPNAME>parking place</TYPNAME>
            <STATUS>closed</STATUS>
            <STATUSWERT k="SONSTIGE" v="miscellaneous">1</STATUSWERT>
        </INFRA>
    </NESTED>
</ROOT>
XML;

function getStatus($doc, $name)
{
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $entries = $xpath->query('//INFRA/NAME');
    foreach($entries as $entry)
    {
        if($entry->textContent == $name)
            return $entry->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('STATUS')[0]->textContent;
    }
    return null;    
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
echo getStatus($doc, 'P Cedar'); // open
echo getStatus($doc, 'D John'); // closed
```

For performance reason, consider extracting all the NAME / STATUS pairs at once (no need to execute the XPath query several times).

Comment: Thank you! I've gone down the DOM/XPath rabbit hole and things are coming together nicely. I appreciate your inputs/examples! There's always something new to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. Xpath expressions allow for complex conditions and casts. So you logic can be put directly into an expression:

- Any `INFRA` element in the document: `//INFRA`
- ... with a child element `NAME`: `//INFRA[NAME]`
- ... that equals `P Cedar`:  `//INFRA[NAME="P Cedar"]`
- ... the `STATUS` children:  `//INFRA[NAME="P Cedar"]/STATUS`
- ... as a string:  `string(//INFRA[NAME="P Cedar"]/STATUS)`

Xpath functions like `string()` take a list of nodes and use the text content of the first node (or an empty string).

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXML());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//INFRA[NAME = "P Cedar"]/STATUS)'));
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//INFRA[NAME = "D John"]/STATUS)'));

function getXML() {
  return <<<XML
<ROOT>
    <NESTED>
        <INFRA>
            <GUID>7C32C0A2-EF31-11E9-8128-4CCC6A98779E</GUID>
            <ID>501</ID>
            <NAME>P Cedar</NAME>
            <TYP>36</TYP>
            <TYPKRZ>50_IN_36_PARKPLATZ</TYPKRZ>
            <TYPNAME>parking place</TYPNAME>
            <STATUS>open</STATUS>
            <STATUSWERT k="SONSTIGE" v="miscellaneous">1</STATUSWERT>
        </INFRA>
        <INFRA>
            <GUID>7C32C0A2-EF31-11E9-8128-4CCC6A98779E</GUID>
            <ID>501</ID>
            <NAME>D John</NAME>
            <TYP>36</TYP>
            <TYPKRZ>50_IN_36_PARKPLATZ</TYPKRZ>
            <TYPNAME>parking place</TYPNAME>
            <STATUS>closed</STATUS>
            <STATUSWERT k="SONSTIGE" v="miscellaneous">1</STATUSWERT>
        </INFRA>
    </NESTED>
</ROOT>
XML;
}
```

To fetch the `STATUS` for all names, you need to iterate the nodes and use them as context (second argument of `DOMXpath::evaluate()`) for detail expressions:

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXML());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$statusByName = array_reduce(
  iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('//INFRA')),
  static function (array $carry, \DOMNode $infra) use ($xpath) {
      $name = $xpath->evaluate('string(NAME)', $infra);
      $status = $xpath->evaluate('string(STATUS)', $infra);
      $carry[$name] = $status;
      return $carry;
  },
  []
);

var_dump($statusByName);
```